# Libreoffice calc: IF formula/function

Tags: libreoffice, calc

Hope you're all having a nice life! :)

I have this sheet in calc with this formula/function:
`=IF(J5>=10;"PASS";"FAIL")`
and it works as it shows "**PASS**" if value in J5 is >=10 and "**FAIL**" when it is not. However, it shows "**PASS**" even if J5 has no value, is blank. Is there a way to make it that it doesn't show anything when no value is present? I'm new using calc so I don't really know how to do what I want. I've been searching for a couple of days but so far none of the things I've tried worked. Thanks in adavance for all your answers.

Comment: `=IF(J5="";"Who knows?";IF(J5>=10;"PASS";"fail"))` ?

Comment: Thanks so much! That works! I did try that something like that as shown here https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/192905/help-with-calculations-using-if-then-else/ but guess did it wrong, anyway, thanks again, your soution works great!